# Mostrar el Linearprogressindicator en el AppBar en un statefulwidget

Tags: android, api, flutter, dart, app

tengo el siguiente codigo donde es un StatefulWidget, en la cual cuando se renderiza muestra un appbar con un menu desplegable, adjunto el codigo. El codigo como les mencione es para un menu en ello se inserta el titulo que tendra en el appbar y el widget osea el screen que se mostrara.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:simao/routes/app_routes.dart';
import 'package:simao/themes/themes.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';

class MenuScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  // Title of appbar
  final String title;
  // Screen to show
  final Widget screen;

  const MenuScreen({Key? key, required this.title, required this.screen}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MenuScreen> createState() => _MenuScreenState();
}

class _MenuScreenState extends State<MenuScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // We need the information of menu options
    final menuOptions = AppRoutes.menuOptions;

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text(widget.title),
          // linear loading bar
          bottom: PreferredSize(
            preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(1.0),
            child:
              Column(children: [

                //
                // This when is loading show the LinearProgressIndicator
                //

                if(true)...[
                  LinearProgressIndicator(
                    minHeight: 2,
                    backgroundColor: AppTheme.white,
                    // valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(AppTheme.white),
                  ),
                ],


              ],
            ) 
          ),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: widget.screen,
      ),
      drawer: Drawer(
        // Add a ListView to the drawer. This ensures the user can scroll
        // through the options in the drawer if there isn't enough vertical
        // space to fit everything.
        child: ListView(
          // Important: Remove any padding from the ListView.
          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          children: [
            DrawerHeader(
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                color: AppTheme.primaryColor,
              ),
              child: Column(
                children: const [
                  CircleAvatar(
                    radius: 40,
                    backgroundImage: AssetImage("lib/assets/logo_app/logo.png"),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 10),
                  Text(
                    "Simao",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 24,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),

            // Recorremos el menuOptions para crear los items
            ...menuOptions.map((item) => ListTile(
                  leading: FaIcon(item.icon),
                  title: Text(item.name),
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.pushNamed(context, item.route);
                  },
                )),

            const Divider(),

            SizedBox(
              width: double.infinity,
              child: ElevatedButton(
                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                  backgroundColor: AppTheme.dangerColor,
                  shadowColor: Colors.transparent,
                ),
                onPressed: () =>
                    Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(AppRoutes.loginRoute, (route) => false),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: const [
                    Text('Cerrar Sesión'),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 10,
                    ), // <-- Text
                    Icon(
                      Icons.exit_to_app,
                      size: 24.0,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Adjunto otro codigo en la cual su funcion es realizar peticiones a un servidor y retornar la respuesta que nos de. Adjunto el codigo.

```
static Future<String> httpRequestAPI({required String rute, required Map<String, dynamic> body, int? timeOutSeconds = 10}) async {

    // SEND REQUEST TO SHOW LOADING ??

    if (!await HttpProvider().checkConnectivityState()) return json.encode(defaultResponses["noInternet"]);
    final url = Uri.https(HttpProvider.urlJFerrer, rute);
    final response = await http.post(url, headers: HttpProvider.headers, body: body)
        .timeout(Duration(seconds: timeOutSeconds!), onTimeout: () {
        return http.Response(json.encode(HttpProvider.defaultResponses['timeout']), 500);
    });

    // HIDE LOADING ??

    return response.body;
  }
```

Me gustaria que cada vez que se haga una peticion, se muestre el Linearprogressindicator en el APPBAR, he intendado muchos metodos para hacerlo pero no me ha funcionado.

Adjunto foto del linearprogressindicador [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: y en que parte haces el llamado a httpRequestAPI,  en el mismo widget? intentaste usar setState?

Comment: Lo tengo separado el httpRequestAPI, el menu lo tengo en otro lugar, por ejemplo el menu solo sirve para mostrar en el app bar en que modulo estas y que se muestre los widgets del modulo. Por ejemplo si quiero hacer un registro ejecuto el httpRequestAPI y ya solo espero una respuesta para hacer algo en el widget del modulo por ejemplo un mensaje de registro exitoso. y si he intentado hacer un setState pero al momento de llamarlo desde httpRequestAPI me pide obligatoriamente el titulo del appbar y el screen que se mostrar.

Comment: hmm lee un poco sobre gestión de estados, en mi canal en yt tengo bastante info, pon : diegoveloper gestión de estados